# Create remote git repository on Windows machine from Pi

Tags: windows, git, raspberry-pi

I have a project I built on a raspberry pi, including a git repository.  I'd like to make it that when I type `git push`, it would push to my windows machine (I've had an SD card fail on me in the past, and it cost me lots of code, so I'd like an external backup).   I've tried many tutorials, all of which fail due to some reason or other.  My latest, is I'm trying to follow [this one](https://elegantcode.com/2011/06/18/git-on-windows-creating-a-network-shared-central-repository/)

I have a windows 10 machine.   I went to `Control Panel`, `System and Security`, `System`, and copied the computer name from `Computer Name`  (`DESKTOP-UFCQ4N8`).

I created a folder called `f:\Shared\Git\thermostat`.    In windows explorer, I right-clicked on here, selected `Properties`, `Sharing` tab, and then clicked `Share`.   I added `Everyone` to users, and clicked `share`

I then did:

```
f:\Shared\Git\thermostat>pushd \\DESKTOP-UFCQ4N8\thermostat

Z:\>mkdir MyGitRepo1

Z:\>cd MyGitRepo1

Z:\MyGitRepo1>git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in Z:/MyGitRepo1/

Z:\MyGitRepo1>popd
```

I finally try the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/devel/thermostat $ git remote add origin file://DESKTOP-UFCQ4N8/thermostat/MyGitRepo1/
pi@raspberrypi:~/devel/thermostat $ git push origin master
fatal: '/thermostat/MyGitRepo1/' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
pi@raspberrypi:~/devel/thermostat $
```

But it does not seem to recognize the repo.   I've spent quite a bit of time playing with different permutations of this, but can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `file://DESKTOP-UFCQ4N8/thermostat/MyGitRepo1/` is certainly not a valid SMB path on the Pi. Try to first get the connection to the network share to work. Or use daemon mode on the host.